# Make an image as a background for a window, and still be able to put buttons and other controls on top of it

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need a way to make an image as a background for a window, and still be able to put buttons and other controls on top of it.

this is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import random
import Tkinter as tk

class MyGame(object):




    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Working Tittle")

        img = Image.open("azure.PNG").convert("L") # convert changes the color to grey etc
        (w, h) = (img.size[1], img.size[1])
        print (w, h)
        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label = Label (self.root, image =tkpi)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        img2 =img.copy()
        pixels = img2.load()
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                pixels[x,y] = 255


        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label = Label (self.root, image =tkpi)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)







        #this is for the canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=200, height=200,bg="blue")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(1, 210,250, 130, fill='green', outline='green')
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 180, 160, 100, fill='grey', outline='grey')
        self.oval = self.canvas.create_oval(2,2,40,40, fill ='yellow', outline='yellow')
        points = [92, 101, 168, 101, 129, 77]
        self.polygon = self.canvas.create_polygon( points,fill ='brown', outline='brown')

        # used for the coordinates
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.button_click)
        self.root.mainloop()

        # this is used to find the coordinate
    def button_click(self, e):
        self.canvas.coords(self.polygon, e.x, e.y)
        print "%d %d" %(e.x,e.y)




MyGame()
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: o sorry every time i ran my program nothing happened it didn't open the window, it just executed without any result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually do this is to a) create a label with the image you want for a background, and b) use `place` to place the image in a containing frame. Doing that, you can continue to pack or grid objects in the frame as you normally would.

For example:

```
self.image = tk.PhotoImage(...)
label = tk.Label(self,image=self.image)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0, anchor="nw")
```

Comment: i tried using ur code but keep getting a run time error: saying it to early to create image

Comment: @user1744316: that means you are trying to create an image before you create the instance of `Tk`. You need to initialize Tkinter before you start using its features.